# Create product compare page like in e-commerce site

Tags: algorithm, e-commerce

I was creating a website(in PHP) which shows information about various Mobile Phones(its not an e-commerce site, but an Informative site), I want to create a feature to compare the selected product(i.e Mobile phones). This feature is seen in most e-commerce sites.
 I just want to know the Algorithm to create this functionality and not the code. I am not using any e-commerce application like prestashop, or any CMS to build this web application, only PHP(PHP, MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

** This is C# Code ** Hope you can use the logic for PHP **

Step #1 – Create a products listing page, for each product add a CheckBox field.

Step #2- Create a link “Compare” that has runs a function. Here is a sample:

```
private void funcCompare()
{

    // REMOVED ALL SESSION
    Session.Remove("arrCompare");
    Session.Remove("catCompare");

    // CREATE NEW ARRAY
    List<string> arrCompare = new List<string>();

    // COLLECT CHECKBOX DATA into ARRAY    
    for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("cbCompare");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            arrCompare.Add(chk.ToolTip);
        }

    }

    // PLACE ARRAY INTO SESSION
    Session["arrCompare"] = arrCompare;

    // GO TO COMPARE PAGE
    Response.Redirect("ProductCompare.aspx");
}
```

The functions gets all the checked items (productID’s) and creates an array and then places that array in a Session("arrCompare");

I then redirect to ProductCompare.aspx page where loop through the array and display each item.

Answer (score 0):

Just display the information from one phone next to the information of the other phone. How it looks on the page is up to you and it depends on what info you want to be most easily compared. The same idea is expandable to more than just a 2-pone compare as well.